# Compute $\frac1{(2\pi)^{2} }\int d^2p \ e^{-l|p|}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}$

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I need compute the integral

$$\frac1{(2\pi)^{2} }\int d^2p \ e^{-l|p|}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}$$

The problem does not specified the limits of integration

The result is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{l}{(\sqrt{\vec{x}^2+l^2})^3}$$

I have tried using

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^\infty dp p e^{-lp} e^{ipx \cos (\theta)} $$

and my result using mathematica is:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty dp  e^{-lp}p J_o(px)$$

But i dont know how to compute this integral to arrive to the results

Comment: Notation fuzzy.  $d^2p$ ?.  Dimension of p ?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\frac1{(2\pi)^2}\int_{{\Bbb R}^2} e^{-l|p|}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}\ d^2p\\
=& \ \frac1{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-lp +ixp\cos\theta}p dp \ d\theta \\
=& \ \frac1{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty p e^{-lp}\cos(xp\cos\theta) dp\ d\theta \\
=& - \frac1{(2\pi)^2} \frac d{dl}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-lp}\cos(xp\cos\theta) dp\ d\theta 
\\
 =&- \frac1{(2\pi)^2} \frac d{dl}\int_0^{2\pi}
\frac{l}{l^2+x^2\cos^2\theta} \ d\theta\\
=& -\frac1{(2\pi)^2}\frac d{dl}\frac{2\pi}{(l^2+x^2)^{1/2} }
=  \frac l {2\pi(l^2+x^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much